# Why is this procedure not adding child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, dom

I have a procedure

```
            newRows = JSON.parse(newRowsStr); 
            var wsr = $('#work-sample-row');
            for (var i = 0, n = newRows.length; i < n; ++i)
            {
                var thisBox = boxHtml;
                var thisNewRow = newRows[i];
                thisBox.find('.work-item-preview-outer').css('background-image', thisNewRow['imageurl']);
                thisBox.find('.work-title').text(thisNewRow['title']);
                thisBox.find('.work-descr-short').text(thisNewRow['sumsmall']);
                wsr.append(thisBox); 
                setTimeout(function(){thisBox.css('opacity','0');}, i * 200)
            }
```

where

```
boxHtml = $('<div class="mb-30-for-mobile col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 work-column" style="opacity:0;"><a class="work-link-wrap"><div class="work-item-preview-outer"><div class="work-item-preview-inner"><h3 class="work-title"></h3><p class="work-descr-short"></p></div></div></a></div>');
```

and what this is meant to do inside the loop is create copies of `boxHtml` and add some text and styles and then make each of those copies a child of `$('#work-sample-row')`. I'm not seeing any errors in the console, but I'm also not seeing the children get added. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `thisBox = boxHtml` you are not creating a copy, just created a new reference to boxHtml. if boxHtml is a jQuery wrapped element try `thisBox = boxHtml.clone();` if it's not a wrapped element do `thisBox = $(boxHtml).clone();`